# SharePoint 2016 SPOfficialFileAction

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, powershell

PowerShell script to move items to record center.  If I use the 'Copy' option, all of the files are copied to the record center but when I use the 'Move' option, it only moves half of the files. I can run it multiple times but it always only moves half.

```
$additionalInfo = ""
$tgtUri = [System.Uri]"http://sharepointsite";
[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPOfficialFileHost] $targetHost = New-Object "Microsoft.SharePoint.SPOfficialFileHost"
$action = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPOfficialFileAction]::Move
$mode = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPOfficialFileSubmissionMode]::None
$targetHost.Action = $action
$targetHost.Explanation = "Move to Archive"
$targetHost.OfficialFileUrl = $tgtUri
$targetHost.ShowOnSendToMenu = $false
$targetDropSite = Get-SPSite "http://archivesite"
$targetDropWeb = Get-SPWeb "http://archivesite"

$DropLibUrl = "http://archivesite/DropOffLibrary/"


$listfiles = New-Object 'System.Collections.Generic.List[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFile]'


[Microsoft.SharePoint.OfficialFileResult] $result = $file.SendToOfficialFile($file.Item.ContentType.Name, $targetHost, $null, $mode, [ref] $additionalInfo)
```

Comment: Where is the loop?  You probably have a memory leak somewhere if you are calling this code multiple times across a set of files.

Comment: sorry, didn't add the loop - here is the basics of it:
foreach($documentsetfolder in $rootFolder.SubFolders)
{
  if ($documentsetFolder.Name -ne "Forms"))
{
  for ($i = 0; $i -lt $documentsetfolder.Files.Count; $i++)
  {                
 $file = $documentsetfolder.Files[$i]
 {
          [Microsoft.SharePoint.OfficialFileResult] $result = $file.SendToOfficialFile($file.Item.ContentType

Comment: The odd part is that it works perfect if you do a copy but if you do a move, it always only moves half of the files, no matter how many files.

Comment: I would take a closer look at the SharePoint logs.  My guess is that the malfunction is an access violation removing the file and its the exception is terminating.

Comment: You need to decrement your For loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command : http://jyothsnag.blogspot.sg/2012/07/programmatically-create-send-to.html

Or create a "Send To Connector" using PowerShell :

http://srinivasvangala.blogspot.sg/2015/11/requirement-configure-send-to-connector.html

Comment: Thanks but it looks like the links are for creating a Send to connection on the webapp.  I need to be able to move the file programmatically.  My PowerShell script works perfectly when I set it to copy but when I set it to move, it always only moves exactly half of the files.